# How do I pass an array modifier as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a `Select` that I'm using from [`Ant Design`](https://ant.design/components/select/) used with react-final-form. So far it looks like this:

```js
const SelectInput = (props) => (
  <AntForm.Item label={props.label}>
    <Select {...props.input}>
      {props.options.map((option) => (
        <Select.Option key={option.id} value={option.id}>
          {option.name}
        </Select.Option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </AntForm.Item>
);

// ....

<AntForm layout="vertical">
  <Field
    label="Select an option"
    name="option"
    options={options}
    component={SelectInput}
  />
</AntForm>
```

The data looks like this from the server:

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, label: 'option1'},
  {id: 2, label: 'option2'},
  {id: 3, label: 'option3'},
  {id: 4, label: 'option4'},
]
```

However as you can you the data has `label` in it. in my select, I'm rendering `name`.

I want to be able to pass a prop that modifies the array to use `label`. I've seen it used in some select components in other libraries, but I interested in how this is done.

i want to do something like this:

```js
<AntForm layout="vertical">
  <Field
    label="Select an option"
    name="option"
    label={options => option.label} // <-- modify to use label here
    options={data}
    component={SelectInput}
  />
</AntForm>
```

How do I achieve something like this? If there's a way to do this with Ant Design, I would love to know as well.

Comment: Do you want to render 4 `SelectInput` with label is option1,option2,option3, option4?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a new props `nameKey`

```
const SelectInput = (props) => (
  <AntForm.Item label={props.label}>
    <Select {...props.input}>
      {props.options.map((option) => (
        <Select.Option key={option.id} value={option.id}>
          {option[props.nameKey || "name"]}
        </Select.Option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </AntForm.Item>
);

<Field
  label="Select an option"
  name="option"
  nameKey="label"
  options={data}
  component={SelectInput}
/>
```